# Probability of at least a woman or at least a right-handed person

Tags: probability

There are 10 people, 4 women and 6 men. Among the men, 3 are left-handed and among the women 2 are left-handed writers. Two people are chosen without replacement. Calculate the probability that the sample contains at least a right-handed person or at least one woman.

I'm trying to solve the following question but I really don't know how to start it! Can someone help me?

I believe I need to use combinations as I can choose a right-handed person in the first or second draw (the same for the woman) but I'm stuck in how to compute it.

I know that the asked probability is P $=\frac{14}{15} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  A sample that does not contain "at least one right-handed person or at least one woman" consists only of left-handed men.

Comment: I'm trying o use your hint. Let's denote A: at least one right-handed person; B: at least one woman; C: a sample that does not contain "at least one right-handed person or at least one woman". So, the problem is asking P(A$\cup$B), right? And P(C) = $\frac{3}{10} \cdot \frac{2}{9} = \frac{1}{5}$. So, P(A$\cup$B) = 1 - P(C)? If so, P(A$\cup$B) =  1 - $\frac{1}{5}$ = $\frac{4}{5}$. Is that? I know that the correct answer of this question is $\frac{14}{15}$. I cannot figure out my mistake

Comment: The order in which the people are selected does not matter.  The number of ways two of the ten people can be selected is $$\binom{10}{2} = \frac{10!}{2!8!} = \frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8!}{2 \cdot 1 \cdot 8!} = \frac{10 \cdot 9}{2} = 5 \cdot 9 = 45$$  The number of ways two of the three left-handed men can be selected is $$\binom{3}{2} = \frac{3!}{2!1!} = \frac{3 \cdot 2!}{2! \cdot 1} = 3$$  Thus, the probability of selecting two left-handed men is $$P(C) = \frac{3}{45} = \frac{1}{15}$$ so the desired probability is $$P(A \cup B) = 1 - \frac{1}{15} = \frac{14}{15}$$

Comment: @Rods2292: On looking at your attempt again, $\frac3{10}\cdot\frac29 = \frac1{15}$, which you computed as $\frac15$ ! Much ado about nothing !

Answer (score 1):

Since *probability* is asked for, here we can also use permutations or simply multiply probabilities.

P($3$ left handed men) $= \dfrac{3\cdot2}{10\cdot9}\; or\;\dfrac3{10}\cdot\dfrac2{9} = \dfrac1{15}$

and take its complement

Answer (score 1):

We can attempt to do this using combinatorics, the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, and the complement rule of probability.

$$P(\geq 1\ right\ handed\ \cup\ \geq 1\ women) = P(\geq 1\ right\ handed) + P(\geq 1\ women) - P(\geq 1\ right\ handed\ \cap \ \geq 1\ women)$$
Where we have used the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to get the above equality.

Now we'll find each of the terms on the right hand side.

We'll use the complement rule of probability to achieve:
$$P(\geq 1\ right\ handed) = 1 - P(0 \ right\ handed)$$
$$P(\geq 1\ right\ handed) = 1 - \frac {5 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2} = \frac {7}{9}$$

Where $\frac {5 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2}$ comes from having a total of ${10 \choose 2}$ groups of 2 and ${5 \choose 2}$ comes from choosing 2 people only of the left handed people.

We can use the same reasoning to get
$$P(\geq 1\ women) = 1 - P(0\ women)$$
$$P(\geq 1\ women) = 1 - \frac{6 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Now we need to take care of over counting which is why we have the subtracting term in our first equation.

$$P(\geq 1\ right\ handed\ \cap \ \geq 1\ women) = 1 - P(0\ right\ handed\ \cup \ 0 \ women) $$
$$P(0\ right\ handed\ \cup \ 0 \ women) = P(0\ right\ handed) +  P(0 \ women) - \\P(0\ right\ handed\ \cap \ 0 \ women) $$
$$P(0\ right\ handed\ \cup \ 0 \ women) = \frac {5 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2} + \frac {6 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2} - \frac {3 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2} = \frac {22}{45}$$

Putting everything together now,

$$P(\geq 1\ right\ handed\ \cup\ \geq 1\ women) = P(\geq 1\ right\ handed) + P(\geq 1\ women) - P(\geq 1\ right\ handed\ \cap \ \geq 1\ women)$$

$$P(\geq 1\ right\ handed\ \cup\ \geq 1\ women) = \frac {7}{9} + \frac {2}{3} - \frac {23}{45} = \frac {42}{45} = \frac{14}{15}$$